# Was Caleb a Demon (or something) or just a really strong human? (Spoilers)

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In Buffy The Vampire Slayer (Season 7), a preacher named Caleb turns up who is super strong and hard to kill. Was he a demon or something, or just a really powerful human?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, major spoilers:

> Caleb was an ex-priest and serial killer who would periodically merge with a non corporeal entity called the First Evil.
>
> This in turn temporarily gave him all of his super powers.
>
> Caleb described the First Evil as being sin itself.
>
> So to answer your question, Caleb was a very charismatic human serial killer who merged with a powerful evil entity.

Answer (score 2):

### Caleb was human.

His entry in the [Buffy the Vampire Slayer Encyclopedia: The Ultimate Guide to the Buffyverse](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33783445-buffy-the-vampire-slayer-encyclopedia) describes him thusly

> *Defrocked priest who began his evil career as a serial killer of women
>   attracted to his charm and religious message*
>
> ...
>
> *Periodically merging with the First, Caleb possessed superhuman
>   strength.*

In the absence of anything to describe him *other than human*, we can assume that he's human.